# How to remove or add sentences that begin with a specific char or string?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like the following:

```
$    CHECK(varlen->get_len() >= HOME_LEN);
$
@    //add more sentences
@    /* some comments */
@    if(varlen->get_len() >= HOME_LEN)
@    {
```

I want to remove lines that begin $ or @ depends on the need. I tried to use the following: Split the giving string and go through each element in the list to check if they start with `$`

```
for sentence in string.split("\n"):
       print(re.sub(r"\b$ \\w-", "", sentence))
```

But it was not working.

Comment: what did expect with `\\w-` ? what are the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
for line in string.split("\n"):
    if not line.startswith('$'):
        print(line)
```

Its a Pythonic way to check if a string starts with another string.

Comment: @TylerGubala he provided context.

Comment: @GravityMass Could you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: @niekas Yes. I am waiting for the 10min delay imposed by stackoverflow before I can mark.

Comment: @niekas just as a follow up, do you know how to remove that character in the beginning? I couldn't just use `string.replace` as some sentences may be like this: `$             Hello $ world` and in here I just want to remove the starting $.

Comment: You can slice the string by `line[1:]`.

Comment: @GravityMass Just like Henry Yik suggested you could slice the string, e.g. `beginning = '$ Hello'; if line.startswith(beginning): line = line[len(beginning):]`.